# iOS - Can I restrict the Subscription Group to different country?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'd like to sale different auto-subscriptions in specific countries due to our business model strategy  (Our app has global released).

for example:

- Subscription (A + B) will be sold in Japan.
- Subscription (B) will be sold in countries except Japan.

We can display different product content by identifying the location or country in our app.

Will this way be forbidden from App review guideline?

Thank you!